# Rails MySQL Too Many Connections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a Rails 2.3 app that is keeping too many MySQL connections open. After less than a day (at ~400rpm) one process had 83 ESTABLISHED connections to the two mysql servers we use.

We're using the mysql2 gem (0.2.18), and the mysql client is: `mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1`.

How can I troubleshoot where these leaks are happening? In our testing, we're never able to leak connections, its only in production.

In MySQL, we can run `show processlist;` to see the open connections. On the app server, we can count the number of connections per pid with `sudo netstat -ntp | grep 3306 | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`.

Comment: What's wrong with 83? The way you're panicking it's like it's 8300.

Comment: There are 84 Rails apps, and our mysql server has a max of 2000 connections. So if all Rails apps have over 23 connections, we run out. Our solution currently is to restart our rails app instances every 5 hours.

Comment: We solved this by adding "wait_timeout: 300" to our database.yml config. That closes unused mysql connections after 5 minutes.

Comment: If that worked, you should add it as an answer and accept it. That way people can find your answer should they have the same problems in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this by adding "wait_timeout: 300" to our database.yml. While that does close the unused mysql connections, it doesn't explain where they came from.

Comment: Are you using any threading with database queries? e.g. `Thread.new { #ActiveRecord query }`. This is a problem I'm having too, but setting the wait_timeout so low isn't really a solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

One random idea: fork the mysql2 gem, add some debugging into Mysql2::Client#initialize, and run your app as normal. You could print a few lines of the stack when the client is initialized, and track down who's causing the leak.

---

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the same problem was occurring on our staging server - it was reaching the max_connections number of connections to mysql. I found that running the service directly from the command line rather than using the start up script got around the issue somehow.

I haven't yet found out what it was in the start up script that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the **Too many connections** error, because I used establish_connection for accessing other databases in multiple models.

I had these models

```
class InternetReference < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :db_webserver
end

class InternetEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :db_webserver
end
```

The solution is to open the connection in an abstract model and inherit from this model:

```
class AppsWebserver < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :apps_webserver
end

class InternetReference < AppsWebserver
end

class InternetEmployee < AppsWebserver
end
```

Now the connections are handled correctly by Rails.